# Quarkus multimodule jar building

Tags: java, quarkus, maven-multi-module

I have a Quarkus multimodule project with a parent controller and a submodule controller. The submodule endpoints are accessible when running the JAR, but I'm facing issues accessing the endpoints from the parent controller.
Is there a way to configure the project or build the JAR in a manner that allows access to all endpoints across both the parent and submodule controllers?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
parent-module
|-- src
|   |-- main
|       |-- java
|           |-- com.example.parent
|               |-- ParentController.java
|-- ...
|-- submodule
    |-- src
        |-- main
            |-- java
                |-- com.example.submodule
                    |-- SubmoduleController.java
    |-- ...
```

only able to control submodule controller APIs

config ,solution that will solve the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.